# mysql LIKE select only the first letter starts with

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to select rows which start with the word `s` but I am getting other results as well. I have rows `red socks`, `blue sweater`, `skirt`.... in the table and when I do the select as below I end up with the above result. I am guessing this is because the red socks contain `s` on the second word, so how can I just select `skirt`?

```
 $pr = 's%' 

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where product like ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pr);
$stmt->execute();
```

rows returned

```
  skirt
  red socks
  blue sweater
```

I only need `skirt`

Comment: Can you execute `SELECT * FROM table where product like 's%'` through `MySQL console` or `PHPMyAdmin` and post the result here.

Comment: @Ravinder I only get `skirt` when I do the query on PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Your query is very clear and should work with `mysqli` too. `echo $pr` before bind and see if it was `'%s%'` !!!

Comment: Try `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $pr);`

Comment: @Rudie That doesn't work. Throws error.

Comment: @Ravinder I did echo and got `s%`.

Comment: What happens if you do `SELECT product FROM table ...` instead of `SELECT * FROM table`?  What columns are in `table`?

Comment: Holycrap `mysqli` prepared statements are weird... After 20 mins of trial and error, it works for me. `o%` works as expected, so your method works for me.

Comment: @Rudie I figured out at the end I had three similar files and was trying to edit the wrong one. It worked as it was expected.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table where product like 's%'
```

You should look at this:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Comment: I am using mysqli prepared statements so this is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `;` after `$pr = 's'`.
Try:

```
$pr = 's'; 
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where product like CONCAT(?, '%')");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pr);
$stmt->execute();
```